# Find the least constant $C$ such that $\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x_ix_j(x_i^2+x_j^2) \leq C(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)^4$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, lagrange-multiplier, holder-inequality

Find the least constant $C$ such that for all nonnegative real numbers $x_1,x_2,.......,x_n$ $$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x_ix_j(x_i^2+x_j^2) \leq C(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)^4$$

My progress so far ;
I worked on the expression to find that $$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x_ix_j(x_i^2+x_j^2)=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^nx_j^3(x_k-x_j)$$ which further simplifies to $$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^3-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^4$$ So to problem reduces to finding a constant $C$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^3 \leq C(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)^4+\sum_{i=1}^nx_j^4$$ where. I'm kinda stuck here I can't figure out which inequality might work.
Any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: The right hand side is the sum to the 4th power or the sum of 4th powers ? Your reasoning is not compatible with the desired inequality

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I am rlly sry for the mistyping

Comment: The problem is treated here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h19778p131846

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a good way to find $C$ :

As in the question, the Inequality is valid $\forall \ n \ge 2,$ thus why not find $C$ for the case where $n=2.$

Then our Inequality becomes $\displaystyle (x_1 = x , x_2 =y) $:

$$\displaystyle xy(x^2+y^2) \le C(x+y)^4 $$

Assume that $x+y = 1$ then we are left to show that $\displaystyle xy(x^2+y^2) \le C$ for some value of C, or in other words, to find maxima of $\displaystyle xy(x^2+y^2) .$

Now using *Lagrangian Multilpier:*

$$
\displaystyle 
\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda) = f(x,y) - \lambda g(x,y) \\ 
\text{where} \ f(x,y) = xy(x^2+y^2) \ \text{is the objective function to maximize}\\
\text{where} \ g(x,y) = x + y  \ \text{is the constraint function } \\ 
$$

Hence, we solving for $\displaystyle \nabla \mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda) = 0$ we get:

$
\displaystyle
x^3 + 3y^2x - \lambda = 0  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ .....(1) \\ 
y^3 + 3x^2y - \lambda = 0  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ .....(2) \\
$

### *Case $1:$*

Subtracting equation $(1)$ from equation $(2)$ gives $x=y,$ as the only possible case. So $x=y=0.5$ to satisfy the constraint $g(x,y)$

Thus $\displaystyle f(x,y) = 0.125 $ and as at this point $\nabla ^2 f(x,y) \ge 0 $ it is a maxima.

Therefore

> $$\displaystyle xy(x^2+y^2) \le 0.125 \implies C = 0.125 $$

### *Case $2:$*

Substitute value of $x$ from $(2)$ into $(1)$ simplify it to get an eqaution in $y$ and $\lambda$:

$$\displaystyle  100z^3 -120z^2 +48z -1 = 0 \\
\text{where} \ y^3 = \lambda z
$$

Here $z = 0.022024 $ is a real solution, using this we can say: $ y \approx 0.28 \lambda^{1/3}$

From this value of $y$ we get $x \approx 0.57 \lambda^{1/3}$ and then using the conatraint we get : $ \lambda^{1/3} \approx 1.7647 \implies \lambda \approx 1.628 .$

Hence from here we get another solution set $\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(0.67,0.329,1.628)$. Therefore $f(x,y) = 0.1233$

Thus,

> $$\displaystyle xy(x^2+y^2) \le 0.1233 \implies C = 0.1233 $$

The point to note is both values are nearly equal, thus we conclude $C = 0.125$.

---

### **EDIT:**

As pointed out by *@TheBestMagician* in the comment, I have added a generalized version:

Let us look for an objective function of general $x_k \ \text{s.t.} \ 1 \le k \le n.$
$$\displaystyle f(x_k) = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} x_k x_i (x_k^2 + x_i^2) + \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} x_k x_j (x_k^2 + x_j^2) = - 2x^4 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_k x_i (x_k^2 + x_i^2)  $$

Now we will define some summations :

$$\displaystyle  S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \ \text{and} \ S_k = S - x_k  \\
  S^3 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^3_i  \ \text{and} \ S^3_k = S^3 - x^3_k
 $$

Thus now we can modify our objective function into:

> $$\displaystyle  f(x_k) = S_k x^3_k + S^3_k x_k. \\ g(x) = S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i  \\ \text{constraint: } g(x) = 1 $$

Then applying Lagrange Mulitplier,

$\displaystyle f'(x_{k-1})=f'(x_k) =  f'(x_{k+1})  = \lambda .$ We can then subtract the functions.

Where, $\displaystyle f'(x_k) = 3(S_k)x^2_k + S^3_k = 3(S-x_k)x^2_k + S^3- x^3_k $

$$\displaystyle f'(x_k) - f'(x_{k-1}) = 0 = 3(S-x_k)x^2_k + S^3- x^3_k -  [3(S-x_{k-1}k)x^2_{k-1} + S^3- x^3_{k-1}] \\ \implies 3S = 4\frac { x^3_k - x^3_{k-1}}{x^2_k - x^2_{k-1}}$$

Assume that $x_k \ne x_{k-1} $, and involve another variable $x_{k+1}$ in the scene as:

$$\displaystyle f'(x_{k+1}) - f'(x_k)  \implies 3S = 4\frac { x^3_k - x^3_{k+1}}{x^2_k - x^2_{k+1}}$$

Similarly assume $x_k \ne x_{k+1} $ and equate both of $S$ values.

> $$\displaystyle  \frac { x^3_k - x^3_{k+1}}{x^2_k - x^2_{k+1}} = \frac { x^3_k - x^3_{k-1}}{x^2_k - x^2_{k-1}} \\ \text{simplify to get} \ x_{k} = -\frac{x_{k+1}x_{k-1}}{x_{k+1}+x_{k-1}}  \ \text{assuming} \  x_{k-1} \ne x_{k+1} \ $$

But here $x_{k-1},x_k,x_{k+1} \ge 0 $ as per the domain. But this contradict the above statement, thus we have to agree on $x_{k-1} = x_{k+1} \forall \ 1 \le k \le n $.

### **Case A:**

Assuming $\displaystyle x_k = x_{k-1} = x_{k+1}$.

Using constraint $g(x) = 1 $, we get $\displaystyle x_1 = x_2 = ... = x_n = \frac{1}{n} $

Hence $\displaystyle  F:\{x_1,...,x_n\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} = \sum_{1\le i < j \le n} x_i x_j (x_i^2 + x_j^2) =\frac{2}{n^4} \sum_{1\le i < j \le n} 1 =   \frac{2}{n^4} \times \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$ Hence

> $$ \displaystyle  F(x) \le \frac{n-1}{n^3} \implies C = \frac{n-1}{n^3} $$

Here we see that $C $ is depended on $n$. We can verify it, for $n=2$ for the above cases I discussed.

Now, for the boundary conditions the function act strangely and keep on increasing its maxima untill it reaches a global max at boundary with only two $x's$ not zero.

We conclude $f(x)$ is always less than or equal to $\displaystyle  \frac{1}{8} .$

Comment: Will it be considered a valid proof at a contest if I just do it for case $n=2$?

Comment: As far as validity is concerned, we know $C$ must be a constant in this case. It means, it doesn't changes with any amount of variables i.e for $n > 2$. Hence to find value of $C$, i do not see anything wrong in calculating it for a simpler case.

Comment: What if the C for, say, n=5 is larger and the inequality with C=1/8 doesn’t hold? We want C such that it holds for all n so I believe this doesn’t work.

Comment: @TheBestMagician, let me verify for a generalized case then. But it was in one of the solutoins in AoPS, that equality holds for $n$ when all of others except any two of $x_i$, are zero. This statement was proposed there.

Comment: @TheBestMagician Check out the generalized version, I have edited it.

Comment: I wasn't able to think of the case $ \displaystyle x_k \ne x_{k-1} = x_{k+1}.$ But will add it soon.

Comment: Looks better now, but I don’t think that’s correct. C should be a constant (your answer gives C=0)

Comment: $C= 0$ for n=1 .... yes , but I guess it is correct.

Comment: For $n=1 \ \ x_i = 1$ thus there do not exist any $x_j$ , thus $x_j=0$

Comment: @TheBestMagician I noted a very strange behaviour of this objective function, at boundary conditions the maxima changes or increases depending upon which type of boundary we are on. Damn this is dynamic. There cannot exist a constant $C.$ And thus for global maxima we have $C=\frac{1}{8}$. Wow... I feel it

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi I don't think you understand. $C$ is a global constant. We want $C$ such that the inequality always holds -- for all $n$. If we take a sufficiently large $n$, using your bound, we can get $C$ arbitrarily close to $0$, i.e. your bound gives $C=0$ and I think it's incorrect. I'm not well-versed with lagrange multipliers, so I can't comment on where you went wrong because I don't know myself.

Comment: @TheBestMagician, Ok now I get what is the issue you are having.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135080/discussion-between-nikola-alfredi-and-thebestmagician).